# How to monitor file changes on a remote machine?

Tags: c++, linux, file, remote-access

How can I open a file on a remote machine and monitor its tail as new data are written to the end of it? There is no specific constraint on the protocol by which the file could be accessed. Any fast and convenient solution would be desired.

Comment: ssh into that machine and use `tail -f /path/file`?

Comment: Aside from vbmaster's suggestion: If you can access the file over the network via a NFS mount or similar, you could use `inotify` to tell you when the file is modified, and write your own implementation of `tail -f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to mount the remote directory to a local directory using the [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) which is a filesystem client based on the SSH File Transfer Protocol:

```
sshfs username@192.168.10.10:/root/Documents/ localDoc/
```

And then access all the files in the local directory as if you were working with remote files.

For performance issues, you can consider using different options like `cache=no` and `large_read`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do ssh to the machine with password less authentication and give the command with ssh itself. For eg :- ssh testuser@test.com 'tail -f filename' or you can use sshpass -p 'mySSHPasswordHere' ssh username@server.nixcraft.net.in "tail -f filename"

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker